# Por que me muestra así el registro?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, pdo, select, paginación

**Buenas, por que me muestra así el registro?**

Nombre artículo: Sección artículo: Precio artículo: País de origen artículo:
Nombre artículo: Sección artículo: Precio artículo: País de origen artículo:
Nombre artículo: Sección artículo: Precio artículo: País de origen artículo:
Nombre artículo: Sección artículo: Precio artículo: País de origen artículo:
Nombre artículo: BALON DE RUGBY Sección artículo: DEPORTE Precio artículo: 15000 País de origen artículo: USA
Nombre artículo: PELOTA TENIS Sección artículo: DEPORTES Precio artículo: 500 País de origen artículo: USA
Nombre artículo: BATE DE BEISBOL Sección artículo: DEPORTES Precio artículo: 25000 País de origen artículo: USA
Nombre artículo: GUANTES DE ARQUERO Sección artículo: DEPORTES Precio artículo: 15000 País de origen artículo: CHINA
Nombre artículo: PELOTA DE PING PONG Sección artículo: DEPORTES Precio artículo: 500 País de origen artículo: CHINA
Nombre artículo: ZAPATOS DE FUTBOL Sección artículo: DEPORTES Precio artículo: 30000 País de origen artículo: USA
Nombre artículo: PANTALON DE ARQUERO Sección artículo: DEPORTES Precio artículo: 20000 País de origen artículo: ITALIA
Nombre artículo: CAMISETA REAL MADRID Sección artículo: DEPORTES Precio artículo: 20000 País de origen artículo: CHINA
Nombre artículo: MAYA DE ping pong Sección artículo: DEPORTES Precio artículo: 5000 País de origen artículo: USA
Nombre artículo: BOLAS DE BILLAR Sección artículo: DEPOROTES Precio artículo: 30000 País de origen artículo: USA
Nombre artículo: ARCO DE FUTBOL Sección artículo: DEPORTES Precio artículo: 150000 País de origen artículo: ITALIA

**Según yo me debería aparecer los datos ordenados pero me aparecen las primeras 4 posiciones vacias, estando en la base de datos todos los campos llenados hasta la posición 11.**

--Este es mi código**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <?php
    
        try{
            
            $base = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname = pruebas", "root", "");
            
            $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            
            $base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
            
            $query = "SELECT NOMBRE_ARTICULO, SECCION_ARTICULO, PRECIO_ARTICULO, PAIS_DE_ORIGEN_ARTICULO FROM PRUEBAS.PRODUCTOS ";
            
            $resultado = $base->prepare($query);
            
            $resultado->execute(array());
            
            while($registro = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                
                echo "Nombre artículo: " . $registro["NOMBRE_ARTICULO"] . " Sección artículo: " . $registro["SECCION_ARTICULO"] . " Precio artículo: " . $registro["PRECIO_ARTICULO"] . " País de origen artículo: " . $registro["PAIS_DE_ORIGEN_ARTICULO"] . "<br>";
            
            }
            
            $resultado->closeCursor();
            
            }catch(Exception $e){
            
                echo "Linea de error: " . $e->getMessage();
            
            }
    
    ?>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Parece que los primeros registros están en blanco en la tabla. Podrás comprobarlo poniendo esto temporalmente dentro del `while`: **`var_dump($registro);`** así verás realmente que trae cada fila. Comenta la línea del `echo` para poder depurar mejor.

Comment: Gracias pero veo la base de datos y no están los campos en blanco. De toda forma comprobaré que qué arroja con el var_dump. Saludos

Comment: Tenías razon, hay cuatro fílas muy delgadas en la base se datos, como las puedo eliminar?.

Comment: Me solucionaste el problema, como puedo poner el ticket verde?

Comment: Realmente no ha sido un gran aporte. Lo importante es que aprendas a usar `var_dump`. Cuando tengas problemas con algo, usa `var_dump($algo);` donde `$algo` sería la variable u objeto que debería arrojarte los datos. Así podrás ver por dentro lo que tiene ese elemento y resolver el problema. En cuanto a las filas en blanco las puedes eliminar con un `DELETE FROM PRUEBAS.PRODUCTOS WHERE IS NULL NOMBRE_ARTICULO` eso en el caso de que esa columna sea nula, porque puede tener espacios en blanco por ejemplo. Lo más seguro es usar el `ID` (si lo tuviere) en el `WHERE`.